# Is possible to add a web map service like streetdirectory to ArcMap/QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, web-mapping

I would like to know if there is some chance to get web map like streedirectory.sg to arcmap or qgis. I need to use this map as a basemap that's why i'm looking for a way how to get this map to ArcMap. Not sure whether arcgis server is available or not. According my research, i didn't find solution so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streetdirectory in particular seems to be proprietary, enterprise-based, and thus they are not giving out a WMS address or anything that could be easily added as a basemap, it seems you would have to pay for this service.

They do have a javascript API, but this would be very difficult to integrate into the QGIS or ArcGIS interface.